# Flattening dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Below I have a dataframe with several columns, all of which I would like to retain after flattening.  This flattening should happen on `name_id` since it represents **longitudinal** data.  I would like to eventually merge this with other dataframes so groupby, though nice doesn't see like a good way to eventually apply machine learning techniques.  That being said, I know there are some pretty bright people out here that could provide opinions about how to approach this based on your own experiences.  Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

```rb
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_id':[1254, 1359, 1254, 1296, 1353, 2656, 1353], 
                   'enrollment_term':['spring 2018', 'spring 2018', 'fall 2018', 'spring 2018', 'spring 2018', 'fall 2020', 'fall 2018'],
                   'gpa_term': [2.93, 3.67, 1.65, 4.00, 3.95, 2.92, 2.82],
                   'course':['math', 'geom', 'alg', 'history', 'art', 'geography', 'donkey ownership'],
                   'dorm_res':[1,1,1,0,0,1,1],
                   'home_work':[0.56, 0.89, 0.95, 0.7, 0.3, 0.64, 0.49]
                   })

df
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Hod new data should looks?

Comment: If I could answer that question I wouldn't be here!  I am wondering what others have done but I'm not really coming across anything of value.  Are you familiar with ML techniques?  I would like to match this up later with an ending dataframe that holds the subset of students that actually graduated.  Eventually I would like to predict graduation based on a multitude of factors but I would like to track student progress in their courses along the way.

Comment: You have to provide more details like @jezrael already suggested. Right now you already have a dataframe that you can use for machine-learning. What exactly are you aiming at and how is your data not already fit for it? Please also keep in mind that "machine-learning" is an extremely broad field...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do.  Here are 3 ways to flatten your dataframe.

```
x=df.values.flatten()
x


x=df.stack().values
x


import numpy as np
np.reshape(df.values, (1,df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]))
```

Result:

```
array([[1254, 'spring 2018', 2.93, 'math', 1, 0.56, 1359, 'spring 2018',
        3.67, 'geom', 1, 0.89, 1254, 'fall 2018', 1.65, 'alg', 1, 0.95,
        1296, 'spring 2018', 4.0, 'history', 0, 0.7, 1353, 'spring 2018',
        3.95, 'art', 0, 0.3, 2656, 'fall 2020', 2.92, 'geography', 1,
        0.64, 1353, 'fall 2018', 2.82, 'donkey ownership', 1, 0.49]],
      dtype=object)
```

Or, perhaps you want to use melt, like this:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name_id'])
```

Result:

```
    name_id         variable             value
0      1254  enrollment_term       spring 2018
1      1359  enrollment_term       spring 2018
2      1254  enrollment_term         fall 2018
3      1296  enrollment_term       spring 2018
4      1353  enrollment_term       spring 2018
5      2656  enrollment_term         fall 2020
6      1353  enrollment_term         fall 2018
7      1254         gpa_term              2.93
8      1359         gpa_term              3.67
9      1254         gpa_term              1.65
10     1296         gpa_term                 4
11     1353         gpa_term              3.95
12     2656         gpa_term              2.92
13     1353         gpa_term              2.82
14     1254           course              math
15     1359           course              geom
16     1254           course               alg
17     1296           course           history
18     1353           course               art
19     2656           course         geography
20     1353           course  donkey ownership
21     1254         dorm_res                 1
22     1359         dorm_res                 1
23     1254         dorm_res                 1
24     1296         dorm_res                 0
25     1353         dorm_res                 0
26     2656         dorm_res                 1
27     1353         dorm_res                 1
28     1254        home_work              0.56
29     1359        home_work              0.89
30     1254        home_work              0.95
31     1296        home_work               0.7
32     1353        home_work               0.3
33     2656        home_work              0.64
34     1353        home_work              0.49
```

Or, maybe this

```
x = df.pivot(index='name_id', columns='enrollment_term', values='gpa_term')
x
```

Result:

```
enrollment_term  fall 2018  fall 2020  spring 2018
name_id                                           
1254                  1.65        NaN         2.93
1296                   NaN        NaN         4.00
1353                  2.82        NaN         3.95
1359                   NaN        NaN         3.67
2656                   NaN       2.92          NaN
```

I don't see any longitudinal data here.